# How to format output using MATLAB's num2str

Tags: string, matlab, string-formatting

I'm trying to ouput an array of numbers as a string in MATLAB. I know this is easily done using [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html), but I wanted commas followed by a space to separate the numbers, not tabs. The array elements will at most have resolution to the tenths place, but most of them will be integers. Is there a way to format output so that unnecessary trailing zeros are left off? Here's what I've managed to put together:

```
data=[2,3,5.5,4];
datastring=num2str(data,'%.1f, ');
datastring=['[',datastring(1:end-1),']']
```

which gives the output:

```
[2.0, 3.0, 5.5, 4.0]
```

rather than:

```
[2, 3, 5.5, 4]
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I just realized that I can use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strrep.html) to fix this by calling

```
datastring=strrep(datastring,'.0','')
```

but that seems even more kludgey than what I've been doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Instead of:

```
datastring=num2str(data,'%.1f, ');
```

#### Try:

```
datastring=num2str(data,'%g, ');
```

#### Output:`[2,   3, 5.5,   4]`

#### Or:

```
datastring=sprintf('%g,',data);
```

#### Output:`[2,3,5.5,4]`

Answer (score 3):

Another option using [MAT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mat2str.html):

```
» datastring = strrep(mat2str(data,2),' ',',')
datastring =
[2,3,5.5,4]
```

with `2` being the number of digits of precision.

Comment: Note that the number of digits of precision cuts the decimals, too. For example `mat2str(123,2)` returns `1.2e+002`.