# MATLAB force num2str to format

Tags: matlab, formatting, string-formatting, precision, floating-point-precision

I'm searching for the reverse of [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057618/how-to-format-output-using-matlabs-num2str)

So when I type `num2str(foo,3)`, I get this :

```
foo=0.00781
foo=0.0313
foo=0.125
foo=0.5
foo=2
foo=8
```

However I want to make them all of the same length, so something like this :

```
foo=0.0078
foo=0.0313
foo=0.1250
foo=0.5000
foo=2.0000
foo=8.0000
```

-How- can I do this with `num2str`? (And I would really appreciate if it also works if `mat2str`)

Thanks for any help!

### Edit :

I noticed that there is another -yet unsolved- part to this problem, which is for numbers greater than 10, or 100, 1000, etc.

So what if I want this : ?

```
foo=000.5000
foo=002.0000
foo=008.0000
foo=032.0000
foo=128.0000
```

i.e. adding leading zeros to a specified length? I tried `'%3.3f'` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For a single number

You can include a C-like [format specifier](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) in [`num2str`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html):

```
>> num2str(.125, '%0.4f')
ans =
0.1250
```

Or use [`sprintf`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
>> sprintf('%0.4f', .125)
ans =
0.1250
```

#### For matrices

Use `num2str` with a matrix input. Include the desired separator column (such a space) in the format specifier:

```
>> num2str([.125 .5; 2 8], '%0.4f ')
ans =
0.1250 0.5000
2.0000 8.0000
```

If you then want `mat2str`-like format, you just need to procress the resulting string to include `;` (or just `;`) at the end of each line and enclose with `[`, `]`:

```
x = [.125 .5; 2 8]; 
s = num2str(x, '%0.4f ');
s = [s repmat('; ', size(s,1), 1)].';
s = ['[' s(1:end-2) ']'];
```

In the example, this gives

```
>> s
s =
[0.1250 0.5000; 2.0000 8.0000]
```

#### Leading zeros

If you want leading zeros to achieve a fixed number of characters, use a format specifier of the form `'%08.4f'`. This means 4 decimal places, 8 characters in total, which gives up to 3 leading zeros. For example,

```
x = [.125 .5; 2 8]; 
s = num2str(x, '%08.4f ');
s = [s repmat('; ', size(s,1), 1)].';
s = ['[' s(1:end-2) ']'];
```

gives

```
>> s
s =
[000.1250 000.5000; 002.0000 008.0000]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was doing this with fprintf, but I didn't know we could use C-like formatting in MATLAB functions too. Well, it only makes sense :)

Comment: Dear @Luis Mendo, (or any other future visitor), please see the edit to my question. Is there a way for leading zeros?

Comment: @halilpazarlama Sure! That's one of the [options of the format specifier](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec). See edited answer